# PHP page not displayed due to SQL query

Tags: php, mysql

This query is not allowing PHP page to be displayed.

```
$sql1="SELECT * FROM `quote_recruiter_posting` ";

$val1 = mysql_fetch_array($sql1);

<?php

    if(strcmp("$val1['desc_ip']","JOB POSTING OFFER"))
    {
        $count1++;
        $in_qry1=mysql_query("update job_jobs set count='$count1'");


    }
    else
    {
       $count1=0;
       $in_qry1=mysql_query("update job_jobs set count='$count1'");"
    }

?>
```

Comment: We really do need more to go on. What is happening? Is there an error being displayed?

Comment: You can't expect us to just magically know what the error may be, we need way more context.

Comment: At first, welcome to stackoverflow. At second, please format your question in a way that is legible and formulate your question a bit more humbly. This is not a service board or anything you pay for, so do not use words like asap. Instead ask for help in a nice way. Also, please at least try to find your errors, before posting.

Answer (score 2):

first execute the query before fetching it. Use the below code

```
$sql1="SELECT * FROM quote_recruiter_posting "; 
$result = mysqli_query($sql1) or die(mysqli_error());
$val1 = mysqli_fetch_array($result);
```

Comment: If you're going to use `mysqli_query` then also use `mysqli_fetch_array`

Comment: yes, i missed the i :), edited it

Answer (score 0):

Try this one

```
$sql1= mysqli_query("SELECT * FROM quote_recruiter_posting "); 
$val1 = mysqli_fetch_array($sql1)
```